# why positive scalar curvature manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am studying scalar curvature and I have seen that many mathematicians studied obstruction against positive scalar curvature (for example Stolz, Schick, Roe, J. Rosenberg, Hanke and  many others). Unfortunately, I couldn't find out why it is important that a manifolds has a positive scalar curvature metric. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: What do you mean by "important" - has practical application? Surely it's inherently satisfying to understand things?

Comment: I am not at all an expert, but to me the point is the distinction between positive and negative curvature. Negative curvature is in some sense "generic" while positive curvature requires your manifold to "curve in on itself" and this puts sharp topological restriction on the manifold.

Comment: to ZevChonoles: Thanks for the attention. For "important" I mean the following: 1) if it has a practical application. For example, maybe there is some problem where people want to find that a manifold is PSC in order to define other things. 2) or maybe if it can tell us something about the topology of the manifolds.

Comment: To  Owen Sizemore: this is what mainly I meant. I read that any a negative function on a manifold can be seen as the scalar curvature of it (the dimension had to be at least 3 if I remember well). I wanted to understand if we understand that a certain manifold is PSC what can we say about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a result by Kazdan & Warner which classifies which functions can be scalar curvatures of some metric. The result states that compact manifolds of dimension 3 or greater come in three varieties:

1. There is no restriction on the possible scalar curvatures; every function is the scalar curvature of some metric.
2. A function is the scalar curvature of some metric if and only if it is negative somewhere.
3. A function is the scalar curvature of some metric if and only if it is either identically zero or negative somewhere.

In particular on every compact manifold, any negative function is the scalar curvature of some metric, but there are certain manifolds, the second and third types above, which do not admit any metric of strictly positive scalar curvature. So negative scalar curvature is not very interesting, but positive scalar curvature is a nontrivial restriction! Nonnegative also arises naturally in general relativity, where any spacetime with nonnegative local mass density (physically a very reasonable condition) has nonnegative scalar curvature. Furthermore, if we foliate a spacetime with maximal slices (spacelike submanifolds with vanishing mean curvature), then if the slices satisfy the dominant energy condition, they must also have nonnegative scalar curvature.

As a final note I'll make a slightly more advanced remark. We can be more precise, at least in certain cases, about the restriction from Kazdan-Warner mentioned above (in fact this result predates their work). Let $M$ be a smooth manifold whose second Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes (this is a purely topological condition). If $M$ admits a metric with positive scalar curvature, then its "A genus" must vanish, a stronger topological condition. This was proved by Lichnerowicz by using a Bochner technique for a differential operator (the "Dirac operator") on sections of a certain vector bundle (the "spinor bundle") over $M$ which we can be sure exists due to the vanishing of the second Stiefel-Whitney class. This implies that the analytical index of the Dirac operator is zero, which in turn implies by the Atiyah-Singer index theorem that the topological index of the manifold is zero, which gives the conclusion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for, especially your words about Kazdan & Warner. I asked this question because I am studying obstruction against positive scalar curvature, like the A-genus, the Rosenberg's obstruction and I wanted to understand why they studied it.